Correspondence between even and odd permutations in $S_5$
I am working on the Davenport constant for symmetric groups, $D(G)$
, which is the minimal number $d$
such that every sequence of $d$
elements in the group G
is one-product sequence, i.e, we can always get identity as a product of some of these elements. Domokos, Cziszter and Szöllősi computed by GAP this constant for all non-abelian groups of order at most 42 and also for $A_5$
, which is $D(A_5)=9$
, i.e., with any sequence of 9 even elements we get identity as product of some of them. Moreover, we also know that maximal one-product free sequences of length 8 consist only of 5-cycles.
Now, I am trying to prove that any sequence of 9 odd permutations in $S_5$
is also one-product sequence and we can always get identity. I am struggling a lot proving this with the computer due to huge computational cost. Is there any correspondence or relation between odd and even permutations so that $D(A_5)=9$
implies this claim? It would be very nice and helpful if you suggest me all the ideas you come up with. Thanks a lot in advance!

If you have a one-product free sequence in a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, and you add to it any $g\in G\setminus H$, you obtain a one-product free sequence in $G$, so $D(S_5)$ is at least $10$. I believe it is easy to see that it is exactly $10$.

I think a sequence of the following $9$ permutations is no one-product sequence: $12$, $23$, $34$, $45$, $13$, $24$, $35$, $14$, $25$

Yes, I agree @მამუკაჯიბლაძე. You are absolutely right, in fact there is a formula so that for a normal subgroup H we know that $D(H) + D(G/H) -1 \leq D(G)$. In this particular case, $D(A_5)=9$ and $D(S_5/A_5)=D(C_2)=2$, hence as you said $D(S_5)$ is at least 10. Any maximal one-product free sequence of length 8 in $A_5$ along with an odd permutation is one-product free in $S_5$. However, how could I prove that it is indeed $D(S_5)=10$?? I don't see how it is that easy to prove it. I'd need to prove that any sequence of length 11 is one-product, but how? Thanks a lor for your help!

@MaartenHavinga $(12)(34)(45)(13)(24)(35)(14)(25)$ is trivial :)

Hi @MaartenHavinga, thanks for your comment! However, I think that (34)(35)(24)(13)(14)(45)(23)*(12) = $1_{S_5}$ (with multiplication from right to left). Thus, it doesn't work.

Some argument like this: each element of $S_5$ is either in $A_5$ or $a\cdot(12)$ with $a\in A_5$, so if you have a sequence $a_1(12)^{\varepsilon_1},...,a_k(12)^{\varepsilon_k}$ with each $\varepsilon_i$ either $0$ or $1$ then its product is $a_1'\cdots a_k'(12)^\varepsilon$ where each $a_i'$ is either $a_i$ or $(12)a_i(12)$ and $\varepsilon$ is the sum of all $\varepsilon_i$ modulo $2$. If $k\geqslant10$ then for $\varepsilon=0$ you can find a subsequence in $a_1',\cdots,a_k'$ with product $1$, while for $\varepsilon=1$ you can find it in $a_1',...,a_{k-1}'$

Thanks @მამუკაჯიბლაძე for your help! Nice approach, I thought a similar strategy few days ago but I got stuck. I still don't see it 100% clear how getting a subsequence in $a_1^{'}, ..., a_k^{'}$ where all elements are in $A_5$ concludes the proof. Shouldn't we take into account the order of multiplication of these elements? Imagine we have $a_2{'}*a_6^{'}*a_3^{'}*a_1^{'}=1_{S_5}$. with $a_i=a_i^{'}$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $a_4^{'}=(12)a_i(12)$... And also taking products in distinct order for your given sequence above in $S_5$ don't we get distinct $a_i^{'}$ in each case?

Similar question from same user, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/474181/davenport-constant-ds-5-10-or-11 (also one on math.stack, but I'll let OP put in the link).
