Davenport constant $D(S_5)=10$ or $11$?
I am working on computing the Davenport constant $D(G)$
of symmetric groups, which is the minimal number $d$
such that every sequence of $d$
elements, possibly with repetitions, is one-product, i.e. there is always some subsequence with product (in some order) the identity element. For example for $S_3$, the Davenport constant is 4 since every sequence of four elements we can always get identity element, however there are some maximal one product-free sequences of length 3, e.g. $(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)$
or $(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2)$.
There is nothing done for symmetric groups and I am using combinatorial proofs, since computations (even with computer) are extremely huge. We know the constant for all non-abelian groups of order at most 42 and $A_5$, for which $D(A_5)=9$.
In particular, now I am focusing on $S_5$ and $S_3^n$. Could someone give me a hint about which strategy to follow, in case you come up with a nice strategy? For $S_5$ I know that $D(A_5)=9$, i.e., every 9 elements in $A_5$ we get identity and I want to prove the same for any 9 odd elements in $S_5$. Moreover, maximal one-product free sequences of length 8 in $A_5$ consist of eight 5-cycles, hence using this information I know that $D(S_5)\le12$
and also $D(S_5)\ge10$, since we get a one-product free sequence of length 9 by taking maximal one-product free sequence of length 8 in $A_5$ and any odd permutation.
I strongly believe it is either 10 or 11 but I do not know how to prove it. I am stuck here, any ideas?

I think that by "subsequence" you allow non-contiguous subsequences, right?

Can you find a sequence of length 5 which is both one-free and inverse-free (i.e. $g$ and $g^{-1}$ don't both appear as subsequence products)?  Then you can join two copies together to make a sequence of length 10.

Also posted to math.stack, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4937972/davenport-constant-of-symmetric-group-s5 without notification to either site, a violation.

And another unlinked question by this same user, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/474161/correspondence-between-even-and-odd-permutations-in-s-5

@BrendanMcKay Thanks for the rwsponse!  Yes exactly, I allow non-contiguous subsequences. In particular, we allow any subsequence $g_{i1}, ..., g_{ir}$ so that the product of elements in some order gives identity. I see what you idea is, however I believe is not enough. Imagine that we find sich a sequence with some transposition, wlog $(12)$. Then, when we take the copy we have two times $(12)$ hence we get identity.

@GerryMyerson I have already deleted those questions in Math Stack. I think there were not appropiated so I tried with overflow. Thanks for your advise!

If $(12)$ is in the sequence then it isn't inverse-free.

"I have already deleted those questions in Math Stack." https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4937972/davenport-constant-of-symmetric-group-s5 is not deleted.

@BrendanMcKay yeah, that's true! However, I have been trying to find such a sequence using GAP computer algebra system and it seems not to be such a sequence! Moreover, I am pretty convinved that $D(S_5)$=10 and hence every sequence of 10 elements is one-product. But I don't know how to prove it...

Am I correct in understanding that the order is nowhere relevant? If so, it would be clearer to talk about multisets instead of sequences.

@PeterTaylor you mean the order of the elements in the sequence or in the product? If you refer to the order in the sequence, you are absolutely right. However, "sequence" is the name used in all papers about the Erdös-Ginzburg-Ziv constant and the Davenport constants, it is somehow a convention.

$120 \cdot \binom{120}{11}$ isn't that large, this might be doable in a few GPU days using $f(S) = \bigcup_{x \in S} (f(S \setminus {x}) \cup f(S \setminus {x}) x)$, although storage is a problem. Perhaps $f$ contains the identity fairly quickly so the actually search space is much smaller than expected? It could also be possible to only compute this up to length 4 and then test all possibilities of using that.

In a comment, Brendan McKay suggested searching for quintuples which are one-free and inverse-free. There are no such quintuples, but there are quadruples, and by repeating elements from one such I present a 10-tuple which is one-free.
Let $\pi_3 = (3, 4, 5)$, $\pi_{32} = (1, 2, 3, 4)$, $\pi_{61} = (1,3)(2,4,5)$. The sequence is $\pi_3^2 \cdot \pi_{32}^3 \cdot \pi_{61}^5$. The following Sage code checks the claim that this is one-free:
S5 = list(Permutations(5))

identity = S5[0]
multiset = (S5[3],) * 2 + (S5[32],) * 3 + (S5[61],) * 5
print(S5[3].cycle_string())
print(S5[32].cycle_string())
print(S5[61].cycle_string())

for order in Permutations(multiset):
    partial = identity
    for elt in order:
        partial *= elt
        if partial == identity:
            print("Failed for", order)

print("Success")

Run it online
Therefore $D(S_5) \ge 11$.

It appears that the typical maximum one-free multisets contain few distinct elements each with multiplicity one less than its order, and that makes some intuitive sense because repeating an element as much as possible reduces the number of distinct products. Thus one strategic idea we can take is to test multisets of this form first in order to get lower bounds.

By exhaustive search, any one-free multiset of 11 elements contains at least 5 distinct elements.

Yes, it makes sense! Thank you so much for your suggestions and help!! I will try to work on that for further cases of $S_n$. By the way, I am not an expert in Gap but I am trying to prove that $D(S_5)=11$ by brute force (almost done), in the last comment you say that any one-free multiset of 11 elements contain at least 5 distinct elements, I guess you have checked all possibilities with only 4 distinct elements and all are one-product sequences, right? Or have you found some one-free multiset of 11 elements?

I also have another request for you. How did you find the inverse-free multiset of 4 elements? I think this idea of getting inverse-free multisets of maximal length could be extremely useful for my master thesis. However,  I've started few days ago programming in GAP and I struggle a bit. I wonder if you would like to share with me an easy program in GAP/SAGE which computes such sequences of maximal length. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

@MikelMartinezPuente, yes, I checked all possibilities with 4 distinct elements. I found the inverse-free multiset of 4 elements by iterative deepening: extend inverse- and one-free multisets of $k$ elements to $k+1$ elements by trying all possibilities. I actually wrote that in Python and just converted to Sage for the answer because it shifts the burden of trusting correctness to Sage's implementation rather than mine. I could rewrite it in Sage, but it's quite naïve (and in particular doesn't exploit the automorphism group to gain efficiency by using representatives of cosets).

@MikelMartinezPuente, Sage code.

Thank you so much! I have already proved indeed that $D(S_5)=11$ by exploiting the automorphism group you mention.
